# reader.ReadString does not strip out the first occurrence of delim

Tags: if-statement, go

I wrote a simple go program and it isn't working as it should:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Who are you? \n Enter your name: ")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if aliceOrBob(text) {
        fmt.Printf("Hello, ", text)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("You're not allowed in here! Get OUT!!")
    } 
}

func aliceOrBob(text string) bool {
    if text == "Alice" {
        return true
    } else if text == "Bob" {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

It should ask the user to tell it's name and, if he is either Alice or Bob, greet him and else tell him to get out. 
 The problem is, that even when the entered name is Alice or Bob, it tells the User to get out.

Alice:

```
/usr/lib/golang/bin/go run /home/jcgruenhage/go/workspace/src/github.com/jcgruenhage/helloworld/greet/greet.go
Who are you? 
Enter your name: Alice
You're not allowed in here! Get OUT!!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Bob:

```
/usr/lib/golang/bin/go run /home/jcgruenhage/go/workspace/src/github.com/jcgruenhage/helloworld/greet/greet.go
Who are you? 
Enter your name: Bob
You're not allowed in here! Get OUT!!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your the `text` is storing `Bob\n`

One way to solve this is using `strings.TrimSpace` to trim the newline, eg:

```
import (
    ....
    "strings"
    ....
)

...
if aliceOrBob(strings.TrimSpace(text)) {
...
```

Alternatively, you can also use `ReadLine` instead of `ReadString`, eg:

```
...
text, _, _ := reader.ReadLine()
if aliceOrBob(string(text)) {
...
```

The reason why the `string(text)` is needed is because ReadLine will return you `byte[]` instead of `string`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the source of confusion here is that:

```
text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
```

Does not strip out the `\n`, but instead keeps it as last value, and ignores everything after it.

> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input,
>   returning a string containing the data up to and including the
>   delimiter.

https://golang.org/src/bufio/bufio.go?s=11657:11721#L435

And then you end up comparing `Alice` and `Alice\n`. So the solution is to either use `Alice\n` in your `aliceOrBob` function, or read the input differently, as pointed out by @ch33hau.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Go, but you might want to strip the string of leading or trailing spaces and other whitespace (tabs, newline, etc) characters.

Comment: Thank you, did not think of that ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
reader.ReadLine()
```

Can leave ‘\n’ but reader.ReadString() can't

Comment: Your answer is confusing. Could you please reformat it and add extra explanation?