# I want to read a file by taking the file name as a user input

Tags: go

I have a JSON file called example.json. I need to read this file by taking its name as user input. I have tried with the below code.

```
func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
    text,_ := reader.ReadString('\n')


    fmt.Println(text)

    file,_ := ioutil.ReadFile(text)
    // os.Exit()
    fmt.Print(file)
}
```

But It's not working properly. I want to take the JSON file name as a command line input and read the JSON file.

I checked with the below method. But it's not matched with my case.

[reader.ReadString does not strip out the first occurrence of delim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100139/reader-readstring-does-not-strip-out-the-first-occurrence-of-delim)

Comment: Can you explain "not working properly" a bit more? What is happening or what error message are you getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reader.ReadString does not strip out the first occurrence of delim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100139/reader-readstring-does-not-strip-out-the-first-occurrence-of-delim)

Comment: @peter the link you have provide, it's only for reading the user input. I already read that user input. I want to read a JSON which have the name user input.

Comment: @TheekshanaSandaru please print the error from .ReadFile

Comment: @TheekshanaSandaru the problem have nothing to do with JSON so , please remove JSON from subject

Comment: always check for all errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first. You can figure out why your code doesn't work if you simply deal with the errors properly. You're ignoring the error thrown when you call `iotuil.ReadFile(text)`.
Just add the proper treatment and you will have a good clue why it isn't working

```
file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(text)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

> : no such file or directory

The reason why your program does not work is likely because there's a break line character in your `text` variable.

From [Go Documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString)

> "*ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input,
>   returning a string containing the data up to and including the
>   delimiter.*"

Remove the break like character from the variable that holds your user's input and it should work, assuming the input actually matches to a existing file including its correct path.

```
func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    text = strings.TrimSuffix(text, "\n")

    //Add the file path
    //or else the user will be required to enter the entire file location
    f := "path_to_the_file" + text 

    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(f)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(file))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think you are better off a simple scan:

```
var namefile string
fmt.Scan(&namefile)

content, err := ioutil.ReadFile(namefile)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Instead of adding a \n and then remove it.