# Reading input from user properly

Tags: go

I'm pretty much new to Golang and I am trying to read input from user which is a name of a file to be opened programmatically.

I tried this initially:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "log"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func takeInput() {
    r, _ := os.Getwd()
    fmt.Println("Your working dir:", r)
    fmt.Print("Enter a file: ")
    f, err := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin).ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    s, err := ioutil.ReadFile(string(f))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(s))
}

func main() {
    takeInput()
}
```

But somehow it always results in:

```sh
$ go run getin.go

Your working dir: /media/DATA/Src
Enter a file: data.txt
2020/07/23 22:21:03 open data.txt
: no such file or directory
exit status 1
```

I have the file `data.txt` within the present working directory.

I googled around a bit and found out that I can use `fmt.Scanln` to take user input too, which worked fine:

```golang
func takeInput() {
    r, _ := os.Getwd()
    fmt.Println("Your working dir:", r)
    var f string
    fmt.Print("Enter a file: ")
    fmt.Scanln(&f)  // what I changed is how input is taken
    s, err := ioutil.ReadFile(string(f))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(s))
}
```

```
$ go run getin.go

Your working dir: /media/DATA/Src
Enter a file: data.txt
100,200,300,445
...
```

Can someone please help me understand what went wrong with using the `bufio.NewReader` for taking user input?

Comment: actually flagging as a dupe: [reader.ReadString does not strip out the first occurrence of delim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100139/reader-readstring-does-not-strip-out-the-first-occurrence-of-delim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs for ReadString:

> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to and including the delimiter.

So the problem with the first approach is that the file name contains a newline at the end. With `Scanln`, it reads until a newline is seen, but it does not include the newline character in the output.

So after taking the user input you can easily trim out spaces by updating your code:

```
func takeInput() {
    r, _ := os.Getwd()
    fmt.Println("Your working dir:", r)
    fmt.Print("Enter a file: ")
    f, err := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin).ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    s, err := ioutil.ReadFile(strings.TrimSpace(f)))  // what needs to be changed
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(s))
}
```

Also don't forget to import the `strings` package.

Comment: Thank you, totally answers the question. Realized that just doing a `strings.TrimSpace(f)` after taking input does the trick. Can you recommend a way which I should use as a standard for taking user input?

Comment: That depends on the use case. For this particular case, Scanln seems sufficient. There are cases where it is not.