# Parsing input from stringreader as int fails with invalid syntax

Tags: go

I am trying to make a program that accepts multiple inputs via the command line, without resorting to using a loop. I'm trying to use recursion, with a "number of input lines" required from the user, but I haven't even gotten that far and I've already hit a snag.

Here's my program so far:

```
package main    
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    stringReader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter num of lines: ")
    testCaseString, _ := stringReader.ReadString('\n')    
    testCaseInt, err := strconv.Atoi(testCaseString)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(2)
    }

    fmt.Println(displayTestCases(testCaseInt))
}

func displayTestCases(testCases int) int {
    if testCases == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    return testCases * displayTestCases(testCases-1)
}
```

When the program asks for the number of lines, entering anything results in `"strconv.Atoi: parsing "2\r\n": invalid syntax` - even numbers (that was a 2 in the sample error. Also tried "2", same result).

I'm not entirely sure what else to do; as mentioned above, I'm very new to this. Is there anything I missed?

How do I take the user input from the command line and parse it as int?

Comment: Trim your Windows line endings.

Comment: @Volker how do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reader.ReadString does not strip out the first occurrence of delim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100139/reader-readstring-does-not-strip-out-the-first-occurrence-of-delim)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`(*bufio.Reader) ReadString`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString):

> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to **and including** the delimiter.

The delimiter `\n` is not an integer therefore trying to convert it to one will fail. So you should cleanup the input before feeding it to `strconv.Atoi`.

> how do i do that?

In this case you could use [`strings.TrimSpace`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSpace):

> TrimSpace returns a slice of the string s, with all leading and trailing **white space removed, as defined by Unicode**.

(this includes `\n` and `\r`)

https://play.golang.org/p/1GeatOSAdi6